# AWS SQS pricing with JPM Listeners

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html
In AWS documentation, they have suggested approach with JMS listener under "Receiving messages asynchronously" section. After 1 million request aws sqs costs 0.4$ per request usually. Under the hood, listener is polling only. Will AWS charge us for each poll request it makes internally when we use listener or for each received message?
Could not find this information on AWS billing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling SQS also count towards request. Receiving a message or not is another metric and is called size of payload. So 1 million free requests in SQS also include polling (both long and short).

ref: https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/

`API Actions    Every Amazon SQS action counts as a request.`

Comment: But we are not polling from SQS, internally they have implemented listeners such a way and AWS is polling

Comment: AWS poll or you poll. From SQS perspective both are API calls and counted towards the quota. So even if you use ANY API provided by AWS or use any SDKs provided by AWS or CLI commands; the end result is the same. It will be counted as a request.